# how to add object to one array from another

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

what i am trying to do is loop through an array of images (parentArray) to add the image to 5 different arrays according to what kind of image it is and when i add an image i want to remove that image from the parentArray. ive tried this but i get a thread error. any ideas would help. thanks in advance.

the code :

```
var index = parentArray.count

    for i in parentArray {

        if i.Type == Kind.S && i.cState == Color.blue {
            parentArray.removeAtIndex(index)
            childArray1.append(i)

        }
```

Comment: A simpler approach is to add the images that don't match any of the 5 cases to a sixth array and replace parent array with that at the end, otherwise you are trying to mutate the array that is being iterated and that won't work

Answer (score 0):

Indexing starts at zero, so parentArray.count will be accessing out of bounds memory.

A second error is that once you have removed one element from parentArray (assuming you were accessing the last index), its total size is less. However, next element you try to remove is the same number, which causes another array indexing issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you are trying to remove the object from the index `parentArray.count` which will always be out of the bounds of the array index. You also never change the value of `index`. So each time your if statement is met, it will try and remove from the index `parentArray.count`.

```
var index = 0

for i in parentArray {

    if i.Type == Kind.S && i.cState == Color.blue {
        parentArray.removeAtIndex(index)
        childArray1.append(i)
    }
    else {
        i++
    }
}
```